# Integral involving square and square root

Tags: calculus, integration, substitution

I have been trying to solve the integral:

\begin{equation}
\int \frac{((n-1)^2 - 4n \gamma e^{\frac{\gamma}{\lambda} t})^{\frac{1}{2}}}{\frac{1}{\gamma} + C e^{\frac{\gamma}{\lambda}t}} dt
\end{equation}

where $\gamma , \lambda $ are positive constants.

So far, by using a substitution of variables 
\begin{equation}
u = (n-1)^2 - 4n \gamma e^{\frac{\gamma}{\lambda} t}
\end{equation}

I have got to the integral:
\begin{equation}
\int -4n \lambda \frac{u^{\frac{1}{2}}}{u^2 -2u (n^2 + 1) + (n^2 -1 )^2} du
\end{equation}

but I am quite unsure as to how to proceed from here.

Any help or suggestions would be greatly appreciated, thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the substitution u^(1/2) = v will work.
[p.s.] We can use partial fraction decomposition,
which is the general way of integration of rational function.

$\int \frac{u^{1/2}}{u^2 - 2(n^2+1)u + (n^2-1)^2} du
= \int \frac{2v^2}{v^4 - 2(n^2+1)v^2 + (n^2-1)^2} dv
= \int \frac{2v^2}{(v+1-n)(v+1+n)(v-1-n)(v-1+n)} dv
= \int (
\frac{n+1}{4n}\frac{1}{v-n-1}
-\frac{n+1}{4n}\frac{1}{v+n+1}
+\frac{n-1}{4n}\frac{1}{v+n-1}
-\frac{n-1}{4n}\frac{1}{v-n+1}
) dv$

Comment: It would be good to add more detail to your answer.

Comment: I tried using this substitution earlier but it didn't seem to really simplify the integral